# ArcGIS JavaScript API won't recognize ArcGIS online material that isn't shared publicly

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, google-earth, google-earth-api

I am trying to add KML Layers to the ArcGIS JS API. I have the KML layers hosted on the ArcGIS Online server. This data that I am working with contains some sensitive information and I am trying to use them within a web application that I am creating using JS (includes jQuery), CSS, and HTML. In order for me to see these layers within the web app it appears that they need to be shared publicly on ArcGIS Online. I do not want to do that because of the sensitive content of them, however I am allowed to share them within my Organization or Group on ArcGIS Online.

Unfortunately, the API doesn't recognize my permissions within these groups, and won't display the KML layers. Is there any way that I can get the ArcGIS JS API to recognize my credentials and allow me to view the layers without sharing them with everyone (public)? In other words is there any way that I can leave them shared within the Organization and/or Group and still see them within my web application using the API?

Additionally I am using Google Earth API that has the same issues, a solution to that would be helpful too.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?  Check your dev tools and look at the network calls.  Are you getting like a 503 Forbidden or something on the call to get the KML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use IdentityManager from the API that allows you to sign in with your arcgis.com account and then receive access to the data. Whatever users from your organization that have accounts can sign in as well.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/identitymanager-amd.html

And here is a sample that shows what I think you are trying to do.
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_identitymanager_client_side.html

Comment: Any known solution like this for Google Earth API?

Comment: I'm not positive whether Google Earth app integration is possible, but you could look at the [Working with secure resources](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/ags_secureservices.html) page for starters